# .NET Compact Framework config files

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, configuration-files

I'm developing a **Windows Mobile 5.0 or above** WinForm application using **.NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2** and **C#**.

I need to use a config file to store a Web Service's URL and other information encrypted.

I've read something about **Mobile Configuration Application Block** from Mobile Client Software Factory. Can I use this?

Is there any other kind of "framework" to work with encrypted configuration files on .Net Compact Framework?

Thank you!

Comment: why would you need to encrypt a Web Service's URL?

Comment: why not? It's only an example.

Comment: I only ask because it sounded like security by obscurity

Comment: Well, I don't want users can change configuration's values.

Comment: I thought users on mobile devices can't see the config on winmo anyway? .exe.config isn't a type that has an app assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of encryption are you looking to use?  You could use the AES encryption algorithm [RijndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) for encrypting and decrypting files. (It is supported in the Compact Framework).  [Here](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx) is an example to get you going.